# Hierarchical regression question - choosing control variables

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis

this is my first post so apologies in advance if I'm not very clear or do not have the correct information. ill try to do my best.

I have performed a multiple hierarchical regression using a block of demographics in first entry, then a IV, then another IV then another IV in subsequent steps on a predictor variable.

I initially performed a correlations on the demographic variables and all other variables to see what demographics to include that were significant with the predictor.

I also entered the demographic variables that had significant correlations with the independent variables (except for those that indicated multicolliniarity).

I read somewhere to do this, but now I need to explain in my paper why I did this. can someone help or point me to a resource that explains the reasoning for this methodology?

Thank you.